# В каком python web framework используются полноценные контроллеры?

Tags: python, framework, поиск-библиотек

Привет всем! Сорри за сумбур.
Меня интересует организация контроллеров в стиле Yii, в которых есть before/after action, фильтры, и не нужно каждый экшн прописывать вручную в конфигах)

В иделае нужно что-то похожее на CherryPy, но там каждый доступный метод нужно оборачивать в декоратор, а не хотелось бы лишнего писать руками. Могу на основе черри в принципе, сам запилить велосипед с нужными мне ништяками, но думается мне, что то-то подобное уже существует.

До этого сталкивался только с джангой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

посмотрите на [Flask-Classy](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Classy/). Похоже на то что вам надо.

Comment: может tornado http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ подойдет?